# HtmlUnit FileUpload "size is unknown"

Tags: post, file-upload, htmlunit

I have a simple form which contains an input field for file upload and a button.

I try to set file, click to button but i get a response from server which tells me "the request was rejected because it's size is unknown".

Anyone faced the same problem or have a suggestion?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/WP/amp/filetransfer" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <input type="FILE" name="filee" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="caption:'abc'">
  <input type="button" name="btnSubmit"  value="Upload File" onclick="form1.submit();">
</form>

final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("www.example.com"); 
final HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("form1");

final HtmlFileInput input = form.getInputByName("filee"); 
final HtmlButtonInput buttonsubmit = form.getInputByName("btnSubmit");

input.setData(read("e_201401145.xml"));//i have a method which reads the file content and returns as byte array
input.setValueAttribute("e_201401145.xml");
input.setContentType("xml/text"); 
final HtmlPage responsePage = buttonsubmit.click(); //Response has the error message which tells me: "the request was rejected because it's size is unknown".
```

Comment: If u manually upload the file u give the path of the file so y u r not doing here ??

Comment: if i just use setData method or just setValueAttribute, server behaves like i did not send anything.

Comment: Can you do one thing upload the file manually and before clicking the button check the source code change,where the path of the file is set

Comment: when i set it manually it's not being seen on source code, i can see it only if i browse the dom by firebug.